# Change clientCredentialType to UserName, but using x509 certificate

Tags: wcf, service, client, certificate

I have made a wcf application, and a client. WCF app. have to know what user and password had accessed the service operation. That is what i done:
**Server web config:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
                    <security>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Auth">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                        </clientCertificate>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer"
                        storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                        storeName="My"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Auth" name="Service">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"       bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="IService"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Client config:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
     textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
     <security mode="Message">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="WcfClient" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:30341/WCFAuthTest/Service.svc"
             binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
             contract="Service.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="WcfServer" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
  </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**How i generated certificates:** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/9StepsWCF.aspx 
**Service operation:**

```
    public string TestAccess()
{
    return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

**Client:**

```
            ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Admin";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123";
        Console.WriteLine(client.TestAccess());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And program must return Admin but it doesn't:
http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/3104/returnz.png
**I know that i have to change the clientCredentialType to UserName, but it gaves me an error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass user name and password you must set client credential type to `UserName`. Setting it to certificate is for using client certificates. Here is some [how to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx).

Comment: And i don't need certificate?
You've said in later answer that i need it for encryption, but in msdn tutorial there's nothing about it. If i need certificate, can you post please link for it correct creation(with makecert.exe).

Comment: Sorry that how to article is incomplete. Check [this](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ch%2015%20-%20Internet%20%E2%80%93%20Windows%20Forms%20Client%20to%20Remote%20WCF%20Using%20Message%20Security%20%28Original%20Caller%2c%20HTTP%29&referringTitle=Home) You need certificate for server and your client must use its public key. By setting credentials type to certificate you are saying that you will have certificate for server and each client will have another certificate identifying him.

Comment: Oh Thx for link, there is much useful information, but not what i need. I only need to pass username and password, through a secure connection.

Comment: So why don't you use HTTPS? Secure connection must be secured somehow - certificate is used for that either on transport level (HTTPS) or on message level.

Comment: Some simple questions:
1. How to make x509 certificate 
2. I will have to make certificate for all clients, if not how to do this?
3. There is some concrete tutorials with examples on how to do this?

Comment: Ladislav, can you show a simple example of this, svc config, and how to do a certificate, in that mode, that client do not require certificates..